# CakePHP Debug Error Cannot Find Webroot

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using Zend Studio to debug a CakePHP app locally on a Windows 2008 R2 VM.  When I tell Zend to debug index.php, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: require(webroot\index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **my directory name**

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'webroot\index.php'
```

My directory name ommitted for brevity.

The index.php contains

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

What changes are needed to debug locally?

Comment: Try replacing "DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR" with "/"? AFAIK most web systems use forward slash, although this is windows so I could be wrong. This is just a first thought before trying anything else.

Comment: @Erty Thanks for the suggestion.  I added '/' but am still receiving the same error.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: can I see the \*\*my directory name\*\*? Please feel free to change any identifying data.

Comment: @Erty DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is the PHP native correct directory separator for the platform. Its value is \ in Windows and / in Linux and Mac. So using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is safe.